# extract datetime format from a file name in unix using shell scripting

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp

In `UNIX`,The file format will be like

```
ABCD2013Jan118225516.txt
```

(date & time is appended with file name). I want the output like

`2013-01-01 18:22:55.16`

in date and time format.

Comment: How are we going to select the name, is it 4 characters allways? Is the date 2013-01-01 or 2013-01-11 ?

Answer (score 0):

if the file name is always 4 char then use cut command like

cut -c5-9 file.txt > date.txt
cut -c10-8 file.txt > time.txt
Then you can display the date inside the files

If the filename is not constant use sed command to fetch date and time only.

Thanks